# TinyMce Does not use correct path for loading fonts

Tags: javascript, symfony, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have installed tinyMCE into a symfony application via `bower` and all the files are stored into `web/bundles/tinymce`.

> bower dependencies inside bower.json

```
"tinymce": "^4.3.13",
```

> .bowerrc

```
{
  "directory": "web/bundles"
}
```

I have the following setup:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'bold italic | bullist numlist | link',
    plugins: ['lists advlist link paste'],
    paste_as_text: true,
    skin_url: window.location.origin + '/bundles/tinymce/skins/lightgray',
});
```

the path of the css is this and it works correctly: `http://app.lan/bundles/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css`

everything loads correctly but in the console i get an error saying that tinymce is looking for fonts in a wrong place:

```
http://app.lan/css/fonts/tinymce.woff
http://app.lan/css/fonts/tinymce.ttf
```

and the location of the fonts folder is inside the `lightgray` folder and not inside `css/fonts`

I guess i should expect the correct path to be: `http://app.lan/bundles/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.woff (same for tinymce.ttf)`

Comment: CSS uses sheet-relative paths, html/js use page-relative paths...

Comment: that does not help me much...